# Scroll to top UITableView with double tap on UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I want to simulate the behaviour of twitter or instagram in their list:

When double tap in UITabBarItem, the list is scrolling to top. Somebody knows how can I do this?
I have 4 items in my UITabBarController, all of them are list, so I want to do this thing for all.

The problem is when I tap bar item in a push view of mi list, this function calls and detect double tap before get the root view controller of the navigation.

I hope can be clear with my problem.

```
var previousController: UIViewController?

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    if previousController == viewController{
        if let navVC = viewController as? UINavigationController, vc = navVC.viewControllers.first as? HomeViewController {
            vc.tableBusinessList.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)
            print("same")
        }
    }else{
        print("No same")
    }
    previousController = viewController
}
```

The behaviour is no correct.
When I pop the view with the tab bar item, the root view is on cell 0

[image]

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson I added a gif to show you my actual behaviour

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok so I think the best way to proceed is to check if the viewController with your tableView is visible, if it isn't, then don't call set content offset.

So:

```
var previousController: UIViewController?

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    if previousController == viewController {
        if let navVC = viewController as? UINavigationController, vc = navVC.viewControllers.first as? HomeViewController {

            if vc.isViewLoaded() && (vc.view.window != nil) {
                // viewController is visible
                vc.tableBusinessList.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)
            }

            print("same")
        }
    }else{
        print("No same")
    }

    previousController = viewController

}
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer, it works!. Just a few changes on the third if statement 
 'if vc.isViewLoaded() && (vc.view.window != nil)'
Thats it!. Really Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem at all! I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: I'll edit my answer to make it correct, cheers for the heads up!

Comment: Perfect solution. thank you so much @OlivierWilkinson

Comment: Doesn't scroll to exactly top at once. in ipad.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func scrollToTop() {
        func scrollToTop(view: UIView?) {
            guard let view = view else { return }

            switch view {
            case let scrollView as UIScrollView:
                if scrollView.scrollsToTop == true {
                    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
                    return
                }
            default:
                break
            }

            for subView in view.subviews {
                scrollToTop(view: subView)
            }
        }

        scrollToTop(view: self.view)
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
var previousController: UIViewController?

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        //when user is in FeedViewController and scroll at last record and want to
        if previousController == viewController {
            if let navVC = viewController as? UINavigationController, let vc = navVC.viewControllers.first as? HomeViewController {

                if vc.isViewLoaded && (vc.view.window != nil) {
                    vc.scrollToTop()
                }
                print("same")
            }
        }
        else{
            print("No same")
        }

        previousController = viewController
        return true;
    }
```

Note: I use @Olivier Wilkinson and show how to use at a required place using an extension for a scroll to the top. (Tested for collection view)

Comment: works like a charm. But I have a bug on my side. I'm having 3 bar items and whenever I'm clicking on the last one it somehow messes my "UITabBarControllerDelegate" cause when I go back to the first bar item "func tabBarController" doesn't trigger anymore..any ideea? appreciate whatsoever

Comment: This method call when you tap on tab bar 2 times, when you change tab from 3rd to 1st to need to tap 2 times, try like this.

Comment: I know. It works perfectly with 1st and 2nd tab items . Btw this is implemented in 1st tabbar. But if i navigate to 3rd it s messing somehow my delegate i dont know cause it wont work anymore

Comment: You need to write this method in you main UITabBarController and above method is its delegate method so when user change tabbar it calls automatically.

Comment: Doesnt work on my side. swift 4. I implemented it in Tabbarcontroller class. nothing happens when I tapped the bar item

Comment: you need to tap 2 times it it tap on same tabbar secondtime it will work, put break points and check in which state it go.

Answer (score 1):

Olivier Wilkinsons answer is great, but the scrolling up part doesn't work anymore in Swift 4, so replace

```
vc.tableBusinessList.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)
```

with

```
vc.tableBusinessList.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), animated: true)
```

an you're all set